# Array Sorting not working in JS

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting, bubble-sort

I have array like this
**value = [250, 200, 300, 150, 300]**

I use this code.

```
        for (var j = 0; j < value.length - 1; j += 1)
        {
            if (value[j] > value[j + 1])
            {
                var temp = value[j + 1];
                value[j + 1] = value[j];
                value[j] = temp;
            }
        }
```

But,it's not working. It's results **value = [200, 250, 150, 300, 300]**

I want to acheive this without using inbuilt function.

Comment: with one loop, you do not get a sorted array.

Comment: Single loop sorting is not possible. You can either go with internal sorting method https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort or use sorting algorithms http://khan4019.github.io/front-end-Interview-Questions/sort.html

Comment: Why wouldn't you just do `value.sort()`

Comment: Look at [this answer in SO](http://stackoverflow.com/a/35711454/6196010) which has a lot of links to different sorting algorithms, porperly explained and in pseudocode.

Comment: @adeneo because the teacher wants them to implement it that way....

Comment: @adeneo because he doesn't delete the answer which got downvote

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You should have two loops one inside other to sort array

```js
value = [250, 200, 300, 150, 300]
for (var i = 0; i < value.length; i++)
  for (var j = i; j < value.length - 1; j++) {
    if (value[i] > value[j]) {
      var temp = value[j];
      value[j] = value[i];
      value[i] = temp;
    }
  }

console.log(value)
```

Answer (score 1):

use the below code.

```js
var value = [250, 200, 300, 150, 300];

for (var i = 0; i < value.length; i++) {
  var swapped = false
  for (var j = 0; j < value.length; j++) {
    if (value[j] > value[j + 1]) {
      temp = value[j + 1];
      value[j + 1] = value[j];
      value[j] = temp;
      swapped = true;
    }
  }
  if (!swapped) {
    break;
  }
}
console.log(value)
```

Comment: Please explain your attempt. Just putting working code is not good enough

Comment: it needs 2 loop as defined in bubble sort algorithm to check each pass parellely as defined in algorithm https://www.tutorialspoint.com/data_structures_algorithms/bubble_sort_algorithm.htm

Comment: I know the algo for bubble sort. What I meant was, explain your attempt in your answer, so that if someone without enough knowledge reads your answer, he understand whats happening.

Answer (score 1):

```
var numbers = [10, 3, 5, 1, 88, 6, 12, 28, 16]
for (var i = 0; i < numbers.length; i++) {
   for (var j = 0; j < numbers.length; j++) {
      if (numbers[i] < numbers[j]) {
          var temp = numbers[j];
          numbers[j] = numbers[i];
          numbers[i] = temp;
      }
   }
}
```

console.log(numbers);

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please don't post code-only answers but add a little textual explanation about how and why your approach works and what makes it different from the other answers given. You may also have a look at our ["How to write a good answer"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) entry.